# I am working for (company name) or i am working under (company name)

Tags: british-english

I am working for (company name) or i am working under (company name) which is correct?

Comment: ***Under*** would be fairly unusual in most contexts, but sometimes it would be a reasonable way of conveying the fact that you're currently working [under the aegis of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/under-the-aegis-of-someone) some "outsourcing / contracting company". Particularly if you're normally a freelance worker, and/or for the duration of the current contract, you're wearing clothes that identify you as being a "representative" of the employing company (you're working "under their banner")..

Answer (score 1):

*I work for .... Company Ltd.* (fill in the blanks with the name of the company) would be considered appropriate.

Comment: Yes. "Under" can be misunderstood as "using the name of".